# Cayley–Hamilton and linear dependence

Tags: linear-algebra

> Show that the set $\{A, A^2, A^3, A^4\}$ of $2 \times 2$ matrices is linearly dependent.

Cayley–Hamilton theorem states that every square matrix $A$ satisfies its own characteristic polynomial equation $\det(A-\lambda I) = 0$ such that $A^n+a_{n-1}A^{n-1}+\cdots+a_2A^2+a_1A+a_0I=0$.
How can I show that the given set of matrices is linearly dependent because $I$ is not in the set. Am I missing some subtlety here?

Comment: Sorry, I meant linearly dependent. I'm not sure if your statement applies to linear dependence too. What I'm saying is, is there some definition or workaround that allows me to use the $I$ in the linear combination? Or even just some truth that I am not aware of.

Comment: No problem. Just separated out the question and your attempt for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the characteristic equation of $A$ be: $$A^2+pA+qI=0$$ 
Then $$A^2=-pA-qI$$
Thus $$A^3=-pA^2-qA$$
Hence $$A^4=-pA^3-qA^2$$ That is $\{A^2,A^3,A^4\}$ is linearly dependent. As a superset of a linearly dependent set is linearly dependent, therefore $\{A,A^2,A^3,A^4\}$ is also linearly dependent.

**Edit:** Let $\{x,y\}$ be linearly dependent. Then there exists scalars $a,b$ such that $ax+by=0.$ Hence, $ax+by+0z=0$. Thus, $\{x,y,z\}$ is also linearly dependent.

Comment: Are you saying @Sahiba, that even if you have a set of 100 elements, you only need two elements to be linearly dependent for the set to be known as linearly dependent?

Comment: @Bucephalus Yes I'm saying that.

Comment: OK, that's good.

Comment: @Bucephalus I have added the reason why that is true in the answer.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good explanation @Sahiba. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 9):

The matrix $A$ satisfies its characteristic polynomial, so $$A^2 + a_1 A + a_0I=0.$$ Multiplying by $A$ we obtain $$A^3+a_1A^2+a_0A=0,$$ that is, already $A, \, A^2, \, A^3$ are linearly dependent.

Comment: Wow, that's awesome.

Comment: Sorry @Francesco. Yours is an awesome answer, but I extracted some more info from the other answer. Cheers.

Comment: No problem, but is not the other answer saying the same things as mine? :-)

Comment: Yes it is, so who do I give it to? Let me see if I can select your answer also.

Comment: Just select the answer you prefer, I was only joking

Comment: Nope I can't, the rationale for me choosing the other answer was that I also learned something extra about linear dependent sets. I actually think your answer was a little more elegant, but I learned more from @Sahiba. I will keep an eye out for you next question. Sorry, this was a difficult question to give credit for. I chose on what I learned.

Comment: Oh, ok. Cheers. Thanks.